# Dealing with empty values in matrix decomposition

Tags: missing-data, matrix-decomposition

In matrix decomposition, given some matrix A we find 2 or 3 matrices which have less information than in A but when multiplied together as A' are optimally close to A in some sense. For instance the Frobenius norm of (A-A') is a common thing to minimize. However the problem with the Frobenius norm is that in most matrix decomposition problems (a la the Netflix challenge), the vast majority of the values are missing in A; but the Frobenius norm minimizes the sum of the square of *all* of the elements in A-A'. This include the missing elements (which presumably I have assigned to 0).

So the question is this: How do I deal with the missing elements of the A matrix when doing a matrix decomposition? Are there any matrix decompositions which minimize the difference of A-A' for only the cells that were present in A?

Comment: I expect it would be manageable to code something that follows the method of standard decomposition methods but ignore missing values. Limitations probably become more apparent as you get into that.